# Query Amazon S3 Object Metadata via Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

Spark 2.1.x here. I have a Spark cluster configured to read/write to/from Amazon S3. I can accomplish this successfully like so:

```
val s3Path = "/mnt/myAwsBucket/some/*.json"
val ds = spark.read.json(s3Path)
```

So far so good -- if there are multiple JSON files at that location it reads all of them into a single `Dataset`. I'm looking to somehow obtain the Last Modified timestamp on each JSON file that I read and store it in an array of datetimes. Hence if there are 20 JSON files that I'm reading, I'd end up with an array with 20 datetimes inside it.

**Any idea how I can do this?** Looking at Spark API docs I'm not seeing any way to query S3 objects for their metadata...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not query `s3` information through the Spark API, but rather through the AWS S3 SDK. You can do it like this:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client

val lastModified = new AmazonS3Client().getObject("myBucket","path/to/file").getObjectMetadata.getLastModified
```

Obviously, you will have to download the AWS S3 SDK through Maven and include the dependency. Also I think they might have deprecated the `AmazonS3Client` in newer versions of the SDK, so you may need to make slight changes depending on which version of the SDK you download:)